# vscode insiders connection error after update

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

`Vscode` insiders stopped to work with remote today morning after (unavoidble) update. It doesn't show remote directory, saying

> Connection error: Unauthorized client refused.

and

> Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error:
>   Connection error: Unauthorized client refused.)

Deletion of all remote `vscode` files and killing vscode processes didn't help.

---

The following transcript can be seen in `Output` tab:

```
remote-ssh@0.44.0
linux x64
SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+myserver", attempt 1
SSH Resolver called for host: myserver
Setting up SSH remote "myserver"
Using commit id "MYHASH" and quality "insider" for server
Testing ssh with ssh -V
ssh exited with code: 0
Got stderr from ssh: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
Install and start server if needed
> Found existing installation at /home/dimskraft/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/MYHASH...
> Found running server...
>  
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
>  
> Checking server status with wget
> ==MY-GUID==
"install" terminal command done
Received install output: ==MY-GUID==
Server is listening on port 35693
Spawning tunnel with: "ssh" -L 127.0.0.1:35693:127.0.0.1:35693  -o ConnectTimeout=15   "myserver" bash << 'EOSSH'
echo -e 'Connected to SSH Host - Please do not close this terminal' && sleep infinity
EOSSH
> Connected to SSH Host - Please do not close this terminal
Spawned SSH tunnel between local port 35693 and remote port 35693
Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
Tunneling remote port 35693 to local port 35693
Resolved "ssh-remote+myserver" to "127.0.0.1:35693"
------
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to `1.36.0-insider` helped

Comment: How does one downgrade?